# tinymce select html node with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tinymce, tinymce-4

I've a tinyMCE editor and I would like to get in javascript the entire node of a selected word (by mouse). I can get that just by clicking on the tag at the end of the editor like that :

[image: tinyMCE demo]

So when I click on the `span` button I can see my text is selected and when I run this javascipt line I get what I want :

```
console.log("output : " + tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format : 'html'}));
```

Result :

```
output : <span style="color: #00ff00;">EAM</span>
```

But when I run the same javascript line after selected the text with my mouse pointer I just get the following result :

```
EAM
```

Do you know how can I get the `HTML` format when selecting text by mouse ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `editor.selection.getNode()`?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#getnode

Or if you need html as a string:

```
let node = editor.selection.getNode();
let tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.appendChild(node);
let html = tmp.innerHTML;
```